# Generic type cannot be built from iterator over generic elements

Tags: function, generics, rust, iterator, traits

I need a function which can accept some number of parameters each of a generic type, and be able to apply operations to individual parameters.

My current not working test attempt:

```rust
pub fn gen_test<I>(f: fn(I) -> f32) -> f32
where 
    I:IntoIterator+Default,
    <I as IntoIterator>::Item: Add
{
    let start = I::default();
    let plus_one: I = start.into_iter().map(|p|p+p).collect();
    let value:f32 = f(plus_one);
    return value;
}
```

Thinking along the lines of `I` being some structure which contains multiple values of possibly differing types and implements some iterator over them.

For example:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct SomeStruct {
    x: u32,
    y: f32
}
// I'm not sure how to implement an iterator across differing types
fn some_function(SomeStruct some_struct) -> f32 {
    (some_struct.x as f32 + some_struct.y)
}
fn main() {
    let value = gen_test(some_function);
}
```

Upon `collect` here I am getting the error:

> a value of type `I` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of
> type `<<I as IntoIterator>::Item as Add>::Output` value of type `I`
> cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=<<I as IntoIterator>::Item as Add>::Output>`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need at least 2 different generic type parameters, since `I` can act as a container for some `T` which it can iterate over or be collected from, in that case we can use these bounds:

```rust
use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::ops::Add;

pub fn gen_test<I, T>(f: fn(I) -> f32) -> f32
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T> + Default + FromIterator<T>,
    T: Add<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    let start = I::default();
    let plus_one: I = start.into_iter().map(|p| p + p).collect();
    let value: f32 = f(plus_one);
    value
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c62e076c2a7b55a129d6b6562314271e)

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light it's even less clear now since you are still trying to collect into an `I` so you still need `FromIterator<I>`. Can you update your question to make it even more clear, preferably showing example usages of your function with concrete types?

Comment: Added, little more explanation, I would say don't focus on the code so much, focus on what I say, the code is simply my rough first attempts at venturing into doing the idea.

Comment: I think that's right, I'm still scrambling around this area figuring the things out, but take my vote. Thank you.